Why is my libopencm3 submodule not working?
I'm trying to do the project from this video but my first include for gpio.h keeps getting the error
"include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/cole/bare-metal-series/app/src/firmware.c).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h"C/C++(1696)"
I downloaded the libopencm3 file declared it the submodule and activated the makefile so I'm not sure what else I'm supposed to do.
enter image description here enter image description here
It works if I do it using platformIO but then it gives me an error where it says my 99-platformio-udev.rules is out of date even though I just downloaded it. I think its because I'm on an Ubuntu which I have found to be very weird with usb-c (my labtop doesn't have a regular usb) permissions.

I'm not sure that either of those images is of value. If so, they would be better placed as text. Where is "gpio.h"? Can you please post your makefile (as text delimited by triple back-ticks) so that we can check whether it includes the path at which you expect to find "gpio.h"?

The makefile I used is listed at https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/blob/master/Makefile. As for where gpio.h are at libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/f4/gpio.h(I think rcc.h is refering the the file in the same folder). However even when I change it to #include <libopencm3/include/libopencm3/stm32/f4/gpio.h> it still gives an error. I saw this exact same thing done in another video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEGKD6JQJyM) so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
